# java GC: static variables not lasting through the applications lifetime

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I've always been  told that a static variable lasts the entire lifetime of the application, but I just read this about javas GC that made me questiong that statement:

> Classes may get collected (unloaded) if the JVM finds they are no longer needed and space may be needed for other classes. The permanent generation is included in a full garbage collection.

So the question is what would cause the JVM to do this and would it mean that all static class variables are in a sense "reset"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the question is what would cause the JVM to do this ...

It happens when a **class** is no longer reachable.  In practice, this can only happen if the application (or framework) dynamically creates a classloader, dynamically loads classes, and then the classloader, classes, and instances of those classes all become unreachable by the rest of the application.

It cannot happen with a class that is loaded by the application's primary classloaders because such classes are always reachable.  (For example, by calling `ClassLoader.forName(...)` using the primary classloaders.)

> ...  would it mean that all static class variables are in a sense "reset"?

No.  A better characterization is that the `static` variables have ceased to exist, if they belonged to a class that has been unloaded.  (Much like local variables cease to exist when they go out of scope.)

Note that this only happens if / when the class is unloaded.  And if it was possible for the application to still *observe* the static variables in question, that would be sufficient for the variables to be *reachable* ... which would inhibit the class unloading.

Comment: I probably should have rephrased the reset part. But if I understand you correctly it would go back to its' default value if you were to reload the class. so say that I have a field `public static int life = 42;`, if I change it to 30 unload it and then load it back in the value of life would be 42, right?

Comment: That is correct.  When you reload the class, you get a different type ... as far as the Java type system is concerned.  Each type has its own distinct set of the classes static variables.